# Delete un-seen mesh with Blender

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, mesh, edit-mode

I am wondering if there is a way to delete un-seen mesh with Blender. Here's an example. I have a cube, and it has 3 cubes inside of that cube.

[image: Cubes]

Is there a way to delete the mesh inside of the cube without selecting the cubes manually? This would clear up lots of extra mesh and speed up my render engine. I am using Cycles, so if Cycles has an option to not render hidden meshes, that would be good too. (although deleting them would be better). A Python script would also do. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way I can think of which works for the cube case is:

1. Select part of the outer cube (a single vert will do)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to select connected vertices
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection
4. Delete.

---

To delete geometry not visible from the camera:

1. Enter camera view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
2. Ensure you are in solid shading and that *Limit selection to visible* is enabled
3. Use border select (<kbd>B</kbd>) to select all visible vertices (you may also want to do this with face select enabled to select visible faces too)
4. Grow the selection (<kbd>Numpad +</kbd>)
5. Delete.

[image]

From the camera, there isn't much indication that there are missing faces. Note however that shadows and reflections will be affected.

[image]

Comment: I already do that and it takes a very long time on my advanced models. I was looking to a way to do it more automated. Like Blender doing it for me, just deleting the un-seen mesh.

Comment: By unseen, do you mean literally all the geometry not visible from the camera? Including geometry behind other geometry, not necessarily inside?

Comment: I would prefer to delete inside, but un-seen from the camera is ok too. I think I have a method, but I couldn't figure out any way of activating it through Python...

Comment: I wish there were a way to cut geometry and insert vertices where the view beings to obscure so that *all* geometry not visible currently is removed. That way you're not keeping some geometry that is invisible to the camera between the visible vertex and the invisible vertex
edit: perhaps a combination of the answer above and this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/115669/168825

Answer (score 2):

You could select something of the surrounding object (vertex,edge or face) in *Edit Mode* and select linked <kbd>L</kbd> followed by invert selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>

Faces where all edges are connected to more than 2 other faces (users) can be selected via *Select Menu / Interior Faces*

[image]