# How to slice an object depending on whether it is in camera or not

Tags: camera

I want get that part of the model, that is within the angle of the camera. For the current solution I use a [script](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/4s8k3f/help_with_finding_whether_a_vertex_is_visible/) that selects the vertices. It works ok, but isn't good enough for what I want to do with it. The issue is that a zig-zag pattern is created when vertice A is within the camera-angle and vertice B isn't.

[image]

I imagine a tool that works similar to the knife project and bascically better approximates the edge with more vertices. If you know properties of the camera that might help or similar scripts please let me know.

Because I have to do it a few thousand times, doing it by hand isn't an option.

Ideas:

- Convert the camera object to a different one,
  extrude it far enough and actually use the knife project. If that
  doesn't work maybe I can convert or use an object as a camera
- Remodel the camera

Comment: does a Boolean modifier with a cube aligned with the camera not work?

Comment: @rob Yes that would probably work, but I can't figure out at all how to automatically align it (I have to do it around 30000 times)

Comment: parent the cube to camera? then it will follow any movements the camera makes.

Comment: @rob I used both of your ideas and have a solution now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of rob I've figured out how to do it and to help people that have a similar question in the future I post this answer. It is made in a way so that it is fully scriptable, you can of course do it by hand.

1. Remodel blenders camera
2. Set a real blender camera as parent object. This step can be done in a 
   seperate file if you then append it.
3. Position the parent-camera however you like
4. Extrude the remodeled camera
5. Add a boolean modifier to the remodeled camera and select the other object 
   that you want to cut out
6. Apply the modifier and delete all the stuff you don't need.

Important: For my project I only need the 3D shape, if you need the materials textures etc. you'd have to figure out how to also include it, because it won't be there after cutting (probably just add the boolean modifier to the car)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]